# Configuring gulpfile.js: FIle path **/ means?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am working on configuring my file path in a gulpfile.

When I am looking at other's gulpfile for reference, there is file path that has been written like this:

```
gulp.src("src/lib/**/*.*)
```

What is **/ supposed to mean?

-

From http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

All most people need to know is that `foo/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/` subdirectory, but `foo/**/*.js` will match all files ending with `.js` in the `foo/` subdirectory and all of its subdirectories.

Comment: since both grunt and gulp use node glob underneath, this technique comes straight from there https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src/**/*.ext` means match all elements with extension `ext` inside src and any sub-directory.

Comment: then if I have a path like src/*/images/*.png = match all png inside images inside all sub-directories of src? What's the difference between src/*/images/*.png and src/**/images/*.png?

Comment: @Vennosh the difference is `src/*/images/*.png` won't match stuff like `src/.cache/images/*.png` because * doesn't match the . character for example.

Comment: So do you mean if I have a directory of `src/.cache/images/apple.png` and `src/fruits/images/orange.png`, `src/*/images/*.png` will only find orange.png? But if I use ** we will get apple and orange?

Comment: Yes but `src/**/images/*.png` will match both

Answer (score 1):

It means all directories or in other words all folders.